# Need help understanding a particular Ruby block

Tags: ruby

I introduced the bug shown below into my code the other day and wanted to better understand the implications.

```
File.open('test.txt').readlines do |line|
  puts "#{line} test"
end
```

File.open.readlines does exactly as expected and returns an array containing all of the lines in the file. But immediately following that array is a block. The array returned by readlines calls no member methods, `each` for instance. I'm assuming the block has nothing calling it, therefore it does nothing. In other languages this may have thrown a compiler warning or in C the block would be considered a nested scope and it would execute. But as shown, Ruby (1.9.2) happily runs with no errors, and no output generated by `puts`.

For completeness here's the corrected version.

```
File.open('test.txt').each_line do |line|
  puts "#{line} test"
end
```

I would like to understand the behavior of the first example. Is my assumption correct in that the block is essentially anonymous and didn't execute because nothing called it?

Comment: What I find strange is that if I try `['a','b','c'] {|s| puts "#{s} test"}`, I *do* get an error. `readlines` also returns an array, but that runs without errors.

Comment: Yes! I discovered the same thing. That's one reason I posted this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what is happening in your particular example. When you call

```
File.open('test.txt').readlines do |line|
  puts "#{line} test"
end
```

The block is being passed to the readlines method. The block is not passed to the array that is returned by the readlines method. This is a valid case and thus the ruby interpreter does not complain.

Here is a simpler scenario to illustrate this

Let's say I had a class defined as follows

```
 class Foo
     def bar
     end 
 end
```

Now if I call

```
 Foo.new.bar {puts "hello"}
```

There will be no error from the interpreter and the "hello" will not be printed.

If I yield to the block in bar as follows

```
 class Foo
     def bar
         yield
     end 
 end
```

Then the puts will be executed and you should see hello printed

```
 Foo.new.bar {puts "hello"} # prints hello
```

In summary blocks are passed to methods not objects and you can pass a block to any method in ruby even one which does not expect it.

Comment: This makes sense. Very good answer. Thanks, cause I was wondering too.

Comment: Ah, that's a subtlety I had not considered. Thanks.